# Is there a way to make unit tests while an app is being developed and not build-able?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, xcode5

A Co-worker and myself are working on an app, he is coding the main app, while I write unit tests. we keep running into a problem where the app doesn't build when I want to test things because we are in different phases.

Is there a way to allow me to test completed classes while the app is in this unbuildable state? So that I can just build the classes that the tests are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same solution for the app project and the test project just reference all the dlls from the last stable app build in your test project.

Comment: well, its iOS so there are no dll's but the idea is intriguing. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are not going with TDD (test first, implement after). So, just checkout an early commit (I am guessing you only push code to your remote repo that builds) and start testing that. When you are done, push it. Your colleague should just need to rebase. The problem here, is that you will probably have conflicts (adding a file on the app target and adding a Unit Test class on the testing target, will change the project.xcodeproj file).

Answer (score 0):

If you work in the same code base I would say no - since the code needs to compile. I would recommend working in different branches. When something is ready for test he can merge his stuff back to the main/trunk branch where you are writing your tests. But on the other hand TDD might be a better solution over all, in both cases you will probably end up rewriting a lot of your tests.